# Why my request to update an user on Postman is working even when the ID is incorrect?

Tags: validation, mongoose, postman

I have this function, that updates the User's details:

```
const updateUserController = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req?.user;
  console.log(req.user);
  validateMongoId(id);

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    {
      firstName: req?.body?.firstName,
      lastName: req?.body?.lastName,
      email: req?.body?.email,
      bio: req?.body?.bio,
    },
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
    }
  );
  res.json(user);
});
```

that is my validateMongoId:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const validateMongoId = (id) => {
  const isValid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id);
  if (!isValid) throw new Error("User ID is not valid our found");
};

module.exports = validateMongoId;
```

That is my Route:

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  userRegisterController,
  loginUserController,
  fetchUsersController,
  deleteUserController,
  userProfileController,
  updateUserController,
} = require("../../controllers/users/usersController");
const authMiddleware = require("../../middlewares/auth/authMiddleware");

const userRoutes = express.Router();

userRoutes.post("/register", userRegisterController);
userRoutes.post("/login", loginUserController);
userRoutes.get("/", authMiddleware, fetchUsersController);
userRoutes.get("/profile/:id", authMiddleware, userProfileController);
userRoutes.put("/:id", authMiddleware, updateUserController);
userRoutes.delete("/:id", deleteUserController);
userRoutes.get("/:id", fetchUsersController);

module.exports = userRoutes;
```

And that is my authMiddleware:

```
const expressAsyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../../model/user/User");

const authMiddleware = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  if (req?.headers?.authorization?.startsWith("Bearer")) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
      if (token) {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
        //find the user by id
        const user = await User.findById(decoded?.id).select("-password");
        //attach the user to the request object
        req.user = user;
        next();
      } else {
        throw new "There is no token attached to the header"();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error("Not authorized token expired, login again");
    }
  }
});

module.exports = authMiddleware;
```

The problem is that I'm being able to update the user even when the ID is incorrect in the URL. I would like that when the ID being wrong, it shows an error message. So, What is wrong with my function?

Comment: because the id is coming from the decoded token, not from the req.params.id